# Code layout in the datetime picker does not appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-timepicker

Why when dealing with DateTime picker 
Does not move to layout ​​found by DateTime picker

[image: Output implementation]

This is the class where the existing Aldata Time On Baker :

```
public class Popactivity extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop, container, false);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


    public void show(FragmentTransaction manager, Object o) {}
}
```

This is the class MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction manager =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Popactivity ppp=new Popactivity();
        ppp.show(manager,null);
```

[image: pop activity]

Comment: Your `show` method is empty

Comment: Why do you put it?

Comment: Put what? You are overriding that method. And it's empty. So, yes, nothing is going to show

Comment: What type in the method? I'm still a novice and I follow courses on YouTube

Comment: What write in methood

Comment: I think you just delete that method... You do not need to define it at all. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: If you want to pick a time, there's a guide for that already. Not sure why you're going to YouTube. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not understand what should you type into the method because I am a newbie

Comment: I told you - you type nothing. I'm sorry you are a newbie, but that method does not need to exist. You can delete it

Comment: But it forces me to add them when deleting errors appear

Comment: If you remove `public void show` method, no errors should exist

Comment: And you need to use `ppp.show(getSupportFragmentManager() ,null);`

Comment: Mis has not changed

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nm6d.png

Answer (score 0):

This method does not need to exist.

```
public void show(FragmentTransaction manager, Object o) {}
```

At least, you shouldn't need to override / overload the existing [`show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String tag)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction,%20java.lang.String)) method.

If you delete it, there should be no errors.

This code, for example, compiles fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {

     public static class PopUpFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PopUpFragment pop = new PopUpFragment();
        pop.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);

    }
}
```

Comment: But no way to get rid of this message annoying
android.support.v4.app.fragment 

Comment: I do not understand?

Comment: I want remove the error message (android.support.v4.app.fragment)

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. What is the error?? You have to `import android.support.v4.app.fragment`...